# Complete induction for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I'm having trouble completing this induction proof, if someone could guide me on the right path, help is greatly appreciated.

> Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ be a sequence of integers such that
>
> $a_0 = 3$
>
> $a_1 = 10$
>
> $a_2 = 38$
>
> $a_{n+3} = 30 a_n - 31 a_{n+1} + 10 a_{n+2}$    for all $n \ge 0$
>
> How can i prove that  $a_n = 2^n + 3^n + 5^n$ ?

I know that I have to use complete induction here, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: I think your subscripts are not formatted correctly, and the recursive formula is misleading. Please correct. You have to enclose the subscripts in braces like this: {}

Answer (score 0):

$$  a_{n+1} = 10 a_n - 31 a_{n-1} + 30 a_{n-2} $$

$$
= 10(2^n+3^n+5^n)  \\- 31(2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}+5^{n-1}) \\+ 30(2^{n-2}+3^{n-2}+5^{n-2})$$

$$
=2^{n-2}(40-62+30)
\\+3^{n-2}(90-93+30)
\\+5^{n-2}(250-155+30)
$$

$$ =  2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}+5^{n+1}$$